# How to combine an array using input form

Tags: php, arrays

I have this input form

```
<?php foreach($valueasle["line_items"] as $keys=>$production){ ?>   

    <input type="hidden" name="my_produc[<?php $keys ?>][produc_sku]" value="<?php echo $produc["sku"];?>"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="my_produc[<?php $keys ?>][produc_quantity]" value="<?php echo $produc["quantity"];?>"><br>

<?php } ?>
```

Its output the code below

```
[my_produc] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [produc_sku] => 003193191
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [produc_quantity] => 4
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [produc_sku] => 0031293419
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [produc_quantity] => 3
                )

        )
```

but I wanted it to be like this

```
[my_produc] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [produc_sku] => 003193191
                    [produc_quantity] => 4
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [produc_sku] => 0031293419
                    [produc_quantity] => 3
                )

        )
```

I have no clue how to combine it, I have search all method but I don't know how to use it because I'm confused on how to do it.

Comment: Add $valueasle array value in question.

Comment: $valueasle array value is same like the result that i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to echo the key. display the keys  and try it will work as you expected.

```
<?php foreach($valueasle["line_items"] as $keys=>$production){ ?>   

    <input type="hidden" name="my_produc[<?php echo $keys ?>][produc_sku]" value="<?php echo $produc["sku"];?>"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="my_produc[<?php echo $keys ?>][produc_quantity]" value="<?php echo $produc["quantity"];?>"><br>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Glad to help you. It happens, some times even I forget the small things and struggle :)

Comment: If you are using php 5.4+ you can implement shorttag for echo by enclosing variables in `<?= ?>`, removing the need for writing `echo` every single time.